# Trying to prevent For Loop values with none from being added to Dictionary Python 3

Tags: python, pandas

I am new to python and am trying to write a For loop that iterate over a large text file line by line to extract specific Regex values and add them to a new CSV file.  I am following code I located to solve a similar problem.  My issue is that none values are being added to the dictionary despite using an "if value not None" line.  The output files are printing multiple blank rows in the output csv because all of the none values are included in the list.  Any help would be appreciated. code below:

```
import re
import pandas as pd

list = []

fh = open(r"test_data.txt", "r").read()
contents = fh.split()

for item in contents:
    list_dict = {}

    date_field = re.search(r"(\d{1})[/.-](\d{1})[/.-](\d{4})$", item)

    if date_field is not None:
        date = date_field.group()
    else:
        date = None

    list_dict["date"] = date

    list.append(list_dict)

print(list)

df = pd.DataFrame(list)
df.to_csv("test_export_with_testdata.csv", index=False)
```

Output

```
[{'date': None}, {'date': None}, {'date': None}, {'date': None}, {'date': None}, {'date': None}, {'date': None}, {'date': None}, {'date': None}, {'date': '2/5/2021'}, {'date': None}, {'date': None}, {'date': None}, {'date': None}, {'date': None}, {'date': None}, {'date': None}, {'date': None}, {'date': None}, {'date': None}, {'date': None}, {'date': None}, {'date': None}, {'date': None}, {'date': '2/6/2021'}, {'date': None}, {'date': None}, {'date': None}, {'date': None}, {'date': None}, {'date': None}, {'date': None}, {'date': None}, {'date': None}, {'date': None}, {'date': None}, {'date': None}, {'date': None}, {'date': None}, {'date': '2/7/2021'}, {'date': None}, {'date': None}, {'date': None}, {'date': None}, {'date': None}, {'date': None}, {'date': None}, {'date': None}, {'date': None}, {'date': None}, {'date': None}, {'date': None}, {'date': None}, {'date': None}, {'date': '2/8/2021'}, {'date': None}, {'date': None}, {'date': None}, {'date': None}, {'date': None}]

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Comment: move both `list_dict["date"] = date` and `list.append(list_dict)` in the if code block. Then nothing gets added if it is None

Comment: This statement should be within the first part of the if statement: `list_dict["date"] = date`

Comment: Where you have that `if` block in your program, can you think of a way you can make use of it in order to make sure that `.append`ing to the list only happens `if` the conditions are right?

Comment: This is off-topic but since you're new it's worth saying: don't use `list` as a variable name, it's a builtin class name. You can call your list `rows` since it's the rows of your `DataFrame`, `my_list`, etc., just not `list`. By doing so, you've overwritten the `list` builtin within this scope and this is likely to cause bugs as you write more code. To illustrate, try executing `list(range(10))` after `list = []`, it should create a `list` of integers 0, 1, ..., 9 but it doesn't.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import re
import pandas as pd

list1 = []

fh = open(r"test_data.txt", "r").read()
contents = fh.split()

for item in contents:
    list_dict = {}

    date_field = re.search(r"(\d{1})[/.-](\d{1})[/.-](\d{4})$", item)

    if date_field is not None:
        date = date_field.group()
        list_dict["date"] = date
        list1.append(list_dict)
    else:
        date = None

    time_field = re.search(r"(\d{1,2})[:](\d{2})[:](\d{2})$", item)
    if time_field is not None:
        time = time_field.group()
        list_dict["time"] = time
        list1.append(list_dict)

print(list1)

df = pd.DataFrame(list1)
df.to_csv("test_export_with_testdata.csv", index=False)



Output:

       date      time
0  2/5/2021       NaN
1       NaN  10:41:45
2  2/6/2021       NaN
3       NaN  10:42:45
4  2/7/2021       NaN
5       NaN  10:43:45
6  2/8/2021       NaN
7       NaN  10:44:45
```

Answer (score 0):

You are still running your `append()` if the value is `None`.

If you do not want to include the lines where the `regex` found no result, simply move all of the code into the `if` statement.

```
for item in contents:
    list_dict = {}

    date_field = re.search(r"(\d{1})[/.-](\d{1})[/.-](\d{4})$", item)

    if date_field:
        date = date_field.group()

        list_dict["date"] = date

        list.append(list_dict)
```

Comment: Thank you everyone for the comments.  Adding the list.append(list_dict) to the if statement worked perfect.  I also appreciate the info about not using list as a variable name.  I changed that as well.

Comment: As I added additional code an additional problem came in the output.  When the output is exported to a csv, each new element is printed on a different row.  I want each regex to run and display the values found on each row or the imported text file to display to the output csv.

Comment: Happy to help, and welcome to Stack Overflow. If this answer or any other one solved your issue, please mark it as accepted.